# How does StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer compile to jdk version 50?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jvm

I see the bytecode of `org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` , it's version is 50. 
[image]

But it use jdk 1.8's method : `java.lang.reflect.Parameter`. How does it compile ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Great engineering is the answer

**Spring 4.x** has brought in **Java 8** compatibility in without breaking binary compatibility of their code with **Java 6** and **Java 7**. This means that the framework was compiled using **Java 8's** `javac` but with options `-source 1.6 -target 1.6`.

This means that **Spring 4.x** does not uses any Java 8 language features (like lambdas) but can use classes introduced in Java 8 SDK by carefully guarding their usage.

In the source code for `org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` you can notice annotation `@UsesJava8` which annotates the class which will be used only when **Java 8 or higher** runs the code compiled for **Java 6**.

To see this is action, please note the Spring framework's code which uses this class, for example [`DefaultNameParameterDiscoverer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.java):

```
private static final boolean standardReflectionAvailable =
        (JdkVersion.getMajorJavaVersion() >= JdkVersion.JAVA_18);


public DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer() {
    if (standardReflectionAvailable) {
        addDiscoverer(new StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer());
    }
    addDiscoverer(new LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer());
}
```

There few more **Java 8** APIs used in Spring 4.x codebase like `Optional` and `Stream`.